# Есть ли аналог input type="file" для выбора папки, а не файла?

Tags: html, asp.net

Есть ли аналог

```
<input id="File1" type="file" />
```

для получения пути к папке который выбрал пользователь? Мне нужно получить путь к папке которую выберет пользователь, загружать я ее никуда не хочу, вариант чтоб он выбрал файл в папке не очень подходит с точки зрения удобства. Пишется под ie соответственно решения в котором используется `webkitdirectory directory multiple` не работают.
Используется asp.net web form со всеми вытекающими, но и там аналогичного компонента не удалось найти.

update: в хроме указанная конструкция работает, но вроде она возвращает только имена файлов в папке

Comment: Боюсь, что нет.

Comment: Браузеры по политике безопасности не позволяют работать с файловой системой, потому и подобный функционал там попросту не нужен, хватает обычного выбора файлов. В IE можно получить доступ через ActiveXObject, но это то еще извращение.

Comment: Максимум возможного FileReader API: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader. Есть эксперементальные фичи вроде FileSystem API: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileSystem